# COM object to create a "Open File" dialog under Vista?

Tags: javascript, windows, com, windows-vista

I would like to use the Windows Common Dialog "Open File", to get a file from the user under JScript. This used to be possible using "ShowOpen()" on MSCOMDLG.commondialog object but, I can't find an equivalent way to do this that works under Vista.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Scripting/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/2007-10/msg00444.html

Helps?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably fake it by using CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder( ... ) and use the [BIF_BROWSEINCLUDEFILES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773205(VS.85).aspx) flag

Comment: I (and [others](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1604032)) tried this method, but it is not reliable: "Unspecified error", 80004005 is thrown for non-folders.