# VBScript file open dialog that works in XP and Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript, windows-xp, fileopendialog

In XP, you can use VBScript with the UserAccounts.CommonDialog object to bring up a File Open dialog ([as described here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5310)), but apparently [this does not work under Vista](http://forums.techarena.in/server-scripting/592925.htm).

Is there a VBScript method for File-Open dialogs that will work for both?

Or even one that will work nicely for Vista?

*Disclaimer: I'm a proper programmer, honest, and don't usually work with VBScript - I am asking this question 'for a friend'.*

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401257/com-object-to-create-a-open-file-dialog-under-vista

Comment: +1 for hilarious disclaimer.  Your 'friend' sounds a lot like a 'friend' of mine.  Maybe there should be a support group?

Comment: @Dave Turvey: No, I gave up on it. Wait ... I mean my friend gave up on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple *dot net component* that exposes a **COM interface**, so you can use it in **VBScript** (or any **COM/ActiveX** based technology).

- (1) Create a dot net library type project, expose the classes you want to be COM interoperability (adding **ComVisible** and **ClassInterface** attributes). The *ClassInterface* attribute must be set to **AutoDual** so you can create instances by *late binding*.
- (2) mark the **register for COM interoperability** check-box in the build tab from the project properties dialog.
- (3) build the project, so the component can be properly registered (you have the option to create a **setup project** for your component so it can be easily deployed).

...

```
namespace WinUtility
{
    [ComVisible(true), Guid("32284FD3-417E-45fc-A4A0-9344C489053B"),
     ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class WinDialog
    {
        public string ShowOpenFileDialog()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog d = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (d.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { result = d.FileName; }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Once your component is registered you can instantiate it from VBScript:

```
dim wnd_helper, file_name
Set wnd_helper = CreateObject("WinUtility.WinDialog")
file_name = wnd_helper.ShowOpenFileDialog()
if trim(file_name) <> "" then
    msgbox "file: " + file_name
else
    msgbox "No file selected."
end if
```